# How to merge a dataset with geometry an another with number data?

Tags: data, carto, geocoding, merge

I want to merge a dataset with geometry and another with the number data to use.

In each one datasets are a field (codparr in one, and cod_parro in another dataset) with 51 values(3601701,3601702,3601702,...) in each one that are repeated in the other, to use this field as (2nd file / key field) merge...

but I can´t merge datasets.

I attach an capture
[image]
 ( snap.... ) where you can see that I have not the option to MERGE

Further more, after click in each dataset you can see that there no exist the option of MERGE neither in the dataset with numerical data

[image]

nor in the dataset with the geometry
[image]

**INSTEAD......**

a friend of mine, show me that he has a different screen (with the data view / map view in the upper screen)
[image]
 and have the option, as you can see in capture YES.... whose is similar/equal to the tutorials/guides captures/videos.

Comment: Consider taking a look at the [CARTO Guides](https://carto.com/learn/guides) to learn more about using CARTO Builder.

Comment: Please excuse me, but I have the same problem and solution is NOT working for me. I search in CARTO for a database with Madrid districts and create map with no issue. Then I upload an excel file that contains a column with the same districsts and add the analisys shown in the gif, but I am NOT prompted to choose b etween inner or left, and the operation will erase my geo data so the polygon map is gone. I have tried with any order with both databases/maps, but won´t change anything. Could you please help me? Thanks

Comment: you dont provide an answer to the question. if the given answer does not help you can ask your own question describing what does not work

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123538)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You and your friend are using different versions of CARTO. While your friend is on the older UI, `CARTO Editor`, you're using the newer `CARTO Builder`.

In CARTO Builder, dataset merges or *joins* are not performed in the Dataset View, like in the older CARTO Editor, but in the Map View as an [*Analysis*](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/join-column-from-second-layer).

Here's a GIF showing the steps to perform such a join.

[image: CARTO Builder Inner Join]
*This GIF is showing an **inner join**, where only the records that share the key column in both tables are kept. You can learn about different type of joins [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)*

Do note that this join will perform dynamically, meaning that changes in the source datasets will affect the joined dataset. If you wish to only have a resulting, static dataset with both the geometric and numeric data, you can export the layer and import it again to CARTO.

Comment: Thank you. I visited that zone but ... I couldn´t get the solution. Your answer is perfect  ;-) SOLVED.